# I want a button that restarts my program in python kivy

Tags: python, android, kivy

i am making a app that shows random meme. I want to make a button that reloads my program so that a new meme is generated. So in short you open the app, see the meme, and if you want to look to next meme you have to click the button and the program reloads and a new meme is ganerated....

here is my code..

```
#First Import The Modules!!
import requests
import json
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import shutil
import urllib.request
from urllib.parse import urljoin
import time
import sys

from kivy import app
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.properties import ListProperty, ObjectProperty
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from kivy.uix.image import Image
from kivy.uix.image import AsyncImage
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivymd.utils import asynckivy


#build the class App
class Button_App(App):
    def build(self):
        #request the content from the url
        response = requests.get("https://meme-api.herokuapp.com/gimme")
        #extract the main meme url from json file and print it
        pass_times = response.json()['url']

        #identify the image from that meme url
        image_url = pass_times
        r = requests.get(image_url)
        #convert the image variable (r) to string
        r = str(requests.get(image_url))
        #Let's start the making of UI!!
        f1 = FloatLayout()
        img = AsyncImage(source=pass_times)
        img.size_hint_x = 1
        img.size_hint_y = 1

        btn = Button(text="Exit!",
                     font_size="35sp",
                     background_color=(0, 0, 1, 1),
                     color=(1, 1, 1, 1),
                     size=(32, 32),
                     size_hint=(.2, .1),
                     pos=(130, 50))
        btn.bind(on_press=self.callback)
        f1.add_widget(img)
        f1.add_widget(btn)
        # return the UI:
        return f1

    def callback(self, event):
        exit()
root = Button_App()
root.run()
```

Comment: Why not just add a `Button` that shows a new meme?

Comment: @JohnAnderson can you pls give an example by referring to the code..

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
#First Import The Modules!!
import requests
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from kivy.uix.image import AsyncImage
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.clock import Clock


#build the class App
class Button_App(App):
    def build(self):
        self.img = None
        f1 = FloatLayout()

        btn = Button(text="Exit!",
                     font_size="35sp",
                     background_color=(0, 0, 1, 1),
                     color=(1, 1, 1, 1),
                     size_hint=(.25, .1),
                     pos_hint={'x':0, 'y':0})
        btn.bind(on_press=self.callback)
        f1.add_widget(btn)

        btn = Button(text='New Meme',
                     font_size="35sp",
                     background_color=(0, 0, 1, 1),
                     color=(1, 1, 1, 1),
                     size_hint=(.25, .1),
                     pos_hint={'right':1, 'y':0})
        btn.bind(on_press=self.get_meme)
        f1.add_widget(btn)

        Clock.schedule_once(self.get_meme)

        # return the UI:
        return f1

    def get_meme(self, *args):
        if self.img:
            self.root.remove_widget(self.img)
        #request the content from the url
        response = requests.get("https://meme-api.herokuapp.com/gimme")
        #extract the main meme url from json file and print it
        pass_times = response.json()['url']

        #identify the image from that meme url
        image_url = pass_times
        r = requests.get(image_url)
        #convert the image variable (r) to string
        r = str(requests.get(image_url))

        self.img = AsyncImage(source=pass_times)
        self.img.size_hint_x = 1
        self.img.size_hint_y = 1
        self.root.add_widget(self.img, index=2)

    def callback(self, event):
        exit()
        
root = Button_App()
root.run()
```